# What's the advantage of having a custom type that is simply an array of a another custom type objects

Tags: angular, typescript

`Angular2` defines the following in the `@angular\router\src\config.d.ts`:

```
export declare type Routes = Route[];
```

So then it can be used like this:

```
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";

export const routes: Routes = [...]
```

I don't really understand why create this custom type if I can simply do like this:

```
import {Route} from "@angular/router";

export const routes: Route[] = [];
```

Which seems much more readable to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's mostly a matter of preference, but there is an advantage that you can change

```
 export declare type Routes = Route[];
```

to

```
 export declare type Routes = Stack<Route>;
 export declare type Routes = Set<Route>;
```

without replacing `Route[]` everywhere throughout your application code but the whole application is still using a different type.

It might be advantageous to have more intention revealing names, but using made up type names for collections types can also make it harder to read your code because `Routes` doesn't reveal that its actually an array of routes.

Comment: right, thanks, the one thing that stops me from using `Routes` instead of `Route[]` is that there are no methods to create this type and this `routes: Routes = [...]` still shows it's an array. What would happen to that part if I changed the original code to `Routes = Stack<Route>;`?